# For a given Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory

I am trying now to find for which K or at least to find a set of K for which the equation

$1+(10K+4)^2+(10M+8)^2=(10N+1)^2$

has no solution and the equation

$1+(10K+4)^2+(10M+8)^2=(10N+9)^2$

has only one solution.

Comment: If the 2nd equation has solution $M,N$ then the first has solution $M,-(N+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation always has only one solution when $N=M$, for any given $K$, namely 
$$
M=N=K\cdot (5K + 4).
$$
This is, because for $N=M$ the second equation says $5K^2 + 4K - M=0$. In this case, the first equation says $5K^2 + 4K + 7M + 4=0$, which has only a solution if $5K^2 + 4K + 4$ is divisible by $7$.